# High database CPU usage from Spring Boot with Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, cpu-usage

We have a Spring Boot application which serves a REST API and currently is running in an EC2 (Amazon Web Services) instance, without containers and nothing related with Kubernetes. Two months ago we started to create a new infrastructure based on Kubernetes (using Elastic Kubernetes Service and Fargate) even no one in the company have had done it never. Everything seemed to work correctly but we noticed that our database CPU increases when the containers are running, without them the database CPU rounds 10% at night when nobody uses the application except our background tasks, but when we apply the deployment, service, ingress and horizontal pod autoscaler the CPU usage go up to 70-80% but no one is using it yet.

The database and the old EC2 instance are in a VPC and the Kubernetes cluster is running in another one. I thought it can be the problem, but if I apply the deployment in my local Kubernetes cluster, the database CPU usage seems to be normal.

The deployment file we have written is the one below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: test-api
  name: test-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-api
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  replicas: 1 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: test-api
        app: test-api
        type: api
      annotations:
        jenkinsBuild: "BUILD_NUMBER"
        appVersion: "HARDMAN_VERSION"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-api
          image: blablabla.amazonaws.com/back:test-latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4G
            limits:
              cpu: 2
              memory: 8G
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: api
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djava.awt.headless=true
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/probes/readiness
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 2
            failureThreshold: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 20
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/probes/liveness
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 2
            failureThreshold: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 20
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: test-api-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-api
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-api
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  name: test-api-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: test-api-http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: test-api-https
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test-api
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-api-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    ## SSL Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:blablabla
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
  labels:
    app: test-api-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-api-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

If you need more information I can provide it to you.

We expect the same numbers or similar ones in terms of database usage as the Kubernetes infrastructure is not being used by nobody at the moment